# Textbox input to variable

Tags: python-3.x

I'm coding with python 3 and trying to assign Textbox input to a variable.
This is what I use:

```
  Textbox = Entry(root)
  Textbox.grid()
```

This gives me only the textbox in the gui.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the .get() method of the Entry object:

```
Answer = Textbox.get()
```